# CSRF protection in web2py

Tags: csrf, web2py

I read from the web2py docs (http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/01/introduction#Security) that

> web2py prevents CSRF as well as accidental double submission of forms by assigning a one-time random token to each form. Moreover web2py uses UUID for session cookie.

Would someone be so kind as to explain to me how CSRF is prevented by the above, given that the random token is done for forms on web2py generated pages? Also the UUID in the cookie does not prevent CSRF as cookies get sent with the malicious request automatically, right?

Presumably a malicious site could perform the attack described on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) via external forms:

> ... the vulnerable request looks like this:
>
> ```
> POST http://bank.com/transfer.do HTTP/1.1
> acct=BOB&amount=100
> ```
>
> Such a request cannot be delivered using standard A or IMG tags, but can be delivered using a FORM tag:
>
> ```
> <form action="http://bank.com/transfer.do" method="POST">
>   <input type="hidden" name="acct" value="MARIA"/>
>   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100000"/>
>   <input type="submit" value="View my pictures"/>
> </form>
> ```
>
> This form will require the user to click on the submit button, but this can be also executed automatically using JavaScript:
>
> ```
> <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
> <form...
> ```

These forms won't have the random token protection, or I have misunderstood this terribly?

In addition, won't standard GET requests (which don't change state but return sensitive information) also be vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would someone be so kind as to explain to me how CSRF is prevented by the above, given that the random token is done for forms on web2py generated pages?

CSRF is prevented precisely because the random token is available *only* on web2py generated pages. Therefore, if an attacker attempts to initiate a form submission from a non-web2py-generated page (i.e., a page owned by the attacker), the form submission will not include the random token, and web2py will reject the form submission.

When web2py generates the token, it also stores a copy in the user session on the server (the user session is identified based on the session cookie). When the form is submitted, the submitted token must match the token stored in the session on the server. If there is no token or the token does not match, the submission is rejected.

> Also the UUID in the cookie does not prevent CSRF as cookies get sent with the malicious request automatically, right?

Right, the UUID cookie alone does not prevent CSRF (it just makes it harder to hijack the session) -- protection requires the CSRF token.

> Presumably a malicious site could perform the attack described on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) via external forms:

No, as noted above, an external form will not contain the CSRF token and will therefore be rejected by web2py. In other words, it is not the *presence* of the token that prevents CSRF, it is the *absence* of the token.

> In addition, won't standard GET requests (which don't change state but return sensitive information) also be vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

No, as the attacker does not receive the response returned by the server -- the end user gets that response in the browser. This is why browsers do not allow cross-origin Ajax requests. You might be thinking of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks (one way that web2py protects against that is by automatically escaping any content written into the view).

Comment: Great point about the GET response not received by the attacker - thanks for that!

Comment: Ok, so the CSRF token for web2py forms is meant to protect endpoints that have a form on them from errant POST requests. My point (which wasn't clear, apologies), was how to protect REST APIs from POST requests, which can presumably be generated via a malicious form?

Comment: Yes, the CSRF token referred to in the documentation is for protection of web2py-generated *forms*. If you need to protect a REST endpoint, you can search online for various solutions, including using some kind of token based authentication (if requests are supposed to come exclusively from browsers, you can check the referer and confirm the request is via Ajax).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Anthony!